# When is it appropriate to use public instead of private when defining variables?

Tags: java

I have a list of constants that I would like to include at the top of my class. I first had the idea of using an enum to represent these constants so that they could be accessed at any time from any class.

However then I read that using `public` in this scenario would be appropriate as then other classes would be able to access the constants from within that class. Is this correct?

This is also leading me to ask the question; when is it appropriate to use the keyword `public`?

Comment: Generally, any time it's immutable making it `public` is fine. `enum`(s) are immutable.

Comment: Use `public static final` for constants.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html shows what level of access is granted by the public, private etc.

Comment: "would be able to access" is not same as "would need to access". If constants are only used by your class then making them private will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Oleg is correct. Better create a separate environment class and declare all your constant there and import that package to a class where you want to utilize these constant. For example

```
package com.my.sys.variable;
 class EnvironmentVariable{
    public static final String CONFIG_FILE = "/app/myappl/myconfig.xml";
    //list of other varialbles
}

import com.my.sys.variable.EnvironmentVariable;

class Startup{
 LoadConfig(EnvironmentVariable.CONFIG_FILE);
 //your other codes
```

}

Comment: Please use the Java coding conventions and the appropriate use of capitals and CamelCase in identifiers: class names are CamelCase starting with a capital, field and method names start with lowercase, and constants are ALL_CAPS with underscores.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks for highlighting my mistakes. I updated my code accordingly.